# Is it possible to use facebook like Groupchat in xmpp chat?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

According to my research, there is still a need to invite users before you can add them on your group chat (via xmppchat).. I want it to be like whats on Facebook messenger style where you can add users on your group chat without the need of inviting them.. is that possible on xmpp chat? can someone lead me to a link or at least tell me hows that possible?? please.. im having trouble for a week solving this. by the way im on android.

Answer (score 0):

According to [XEP-0045 section 7.8](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#invite), the protocol states that a user needs an invitation to a MUC.

That being said, a way to handle it is to create a webservice on your server side that acts as an administrator, and takes care of the invites.

A very general way of doing this would be (Would work for both Android and iOS):

Client tries to enter a room (first sends request to server, and sets up an invitation listener). -->>

Server checks if the user is allowed (the point of the invite, determine .if a user is allowed by your logic: e.g. userid). -->>

Server acts as an admin and sends an invite.-->>

Client side invitation listener catches that and goes into the room.

to create as less requests as possible, the Client should cache the roomid for each room he "remembers" being invited to, and check that cache before sending the request.